# Facebook share dialog empty

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Yoast SEO on my Wordpress site,

I have enabled the "Open Graph Meta Data" and added a default facebook og:image. When fetching the site using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ I do not get any errors and the following fields are correctly populated:

```
fb:app_id 
og:url 
og:type = website 
og:title 
og:locale 
og:image 
og:description 
og:updated_time
```

But the share dialog is empty and does only include the url. What can be the reason why the Open Graph Meta Data does not show in the share dialog box?

Comment: Tell us the actual URL, if you want our help.

Comment: _“When trying to debug using facebook sharing debugger everything becomes blank”_ - that should not happen; if anything is wrong on your end, the debug tool should at least tell you what it is. Suggest you file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/